# Delete time from datetime format in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, time, format

I need to send an email with a date, and the date should be "mm/dd/yyyy".

From the database i get the date in this format:

`2017-02-26T23:00:00Z`

So I added `from django.utils import formats` along with all the imports and then I also added in my function `final_date = formats.date_format(input_date, "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")`
The thing is that i get exactly what i want with the date, but also the time.

Is there any way to get rid of the time within my formatting??

I know i can use the function split(), but that seems an ugly way to achieve this.

**TL;DR**

What I have --> 02/20/2017 4:40 p.m.

What I want --> 02/20/2017

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're getting out a datetime object from the database (it's unclear whether you've saved that as a string, for example, but it *looks* like it's being output in `isoformat()` style) - I often get this, for example, when examining a datefield in terminal:

`datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

then you can just do:

`datetime_from_database.date()` to just show the date.  [Docs on this.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date)

Now, that's still not in the MM/DD/YYYY format you wanted - if it's for a template, [you can manage this in the template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date) using:

```
{{ date_ value|date:"m D Y" }}
```

In fact, you can do that even if you haven't managed it already using the `.date()` method mentioned above.

Alternatively, if it's for something else, you can use the [`strftime` formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) to present a string however you like.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` objects have a `date()` method. That's the easiest way to get what you want.

```
final_date = formats.date_format(input_date.date(), "SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT")
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the only thing i needed to do was to change `"SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT"` by `"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"`, and that way we get rid of the time part.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Fields with time are simply `datetime` objects in Python. You should be able to use `strftime` to convert it into the string you want.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime